# Which is the better way to access pageflowscope variable in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, facescontext, requestcontext

As we know there are multiple ways to access the page flow scope variable but which one is the right one?

```
ex RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().getPageFlowScope();
AdfContext.getCurrent.getPageFlowScope();
FacesContext?
```

I am also curios to know what the differences are between all these Contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both methods RequestContext.getPageFlowScope and AdfContext.getPageFlowScope return the same thing. You can use both.